# Defining ‘commands’ or ‘macros’ with unicode names

Tags: macros, xetex, luatex, tex-core

How can I implement the rough equivalent of `\def\macro{expansion}` so that the macro name can contain spaces and other unicode characters? I’d like to be able to do the following, for example:

```
\defineinsert{qty: β2 activity}{\SI{1.85}{\mega\becquerel}}
[...]
The measured activity was \insert{qty: β2 activity}.
$R_\beta = \insert{qty: β2 activity}$
```

*producing*

```
The measured activity was \SI{1.85}{\mega\becquerel}.
$R_\beta = \SI{1.85}{\mega\becquerel}$
```

The motivation is to be able to pre-define many orderly ‘macros’ in to be used throughout a document, without the restriction that characters must only be `[a-zA-Z]`, as imposed by using `\def` to define actual commands.

---

I have no idea how to implement this, since I don’t know how one would create key-value mappings with TeX… or if that would be the right approach.

Perhaps there is another way of filling this need? Should I start using LuaTeX to accomplish this? (I am presently using XeLaTeX.) Perhaps there exists a package for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\csname ...\endcsname` for this. E.g with the help of \@namedef:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\@namedef{\detokenize{qty: β2 activity}}{bllb}

The beta activity \@nameuse{\detokenize{qty: β2 activity}}

The beta activity \@nameuse{\detokenize{qty: β2  activity}}

\end{document}
```

---

For brevity, you may define something like

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\newshortcut[2]{\@namedef{\detokenize{#1}}{#2}}
\newcommand\shortcut[1]{\@nameuse{\detokenize{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

which may be used like so:

```
\newshortcut{qty: β}{lola}
[...]
Hello \shortcut{qty: β}.
```

Comment: Furthermore, by defining `\newcommand\shortcut[1]{\@nameuse{\detokenize{#1}}}`, one may use `\shortcut{qty: β}` in the place of `\@nameuse{\detokenize{qty: β}}` for brevity! This is perfect.